# Rails migration array without default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, migration

Rails 5, Postgres 9

I have >10 millions of records for model. I need to add new field with array type.
From docs I can add new migration as

```
add_column :model, :new_field, :string, array: true, default: []
```

But after it Database blocked because of many Alter operations with setting default value.

Is it real to create new array field without (default: []) value?

Comment: Isn't the default in postgresql an empty array anyway, so why explicitly specify that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a column the table with default value of `null`
2. Update the rows in batches(default 1000) and set `[]` as the value
3. Set the `NOT NULL` on the column

```
class AddCategoriesToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  disable_ddl_transaction!

  def up
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      add_column :products, :categories, :string, array: true

      execute <<~SQL
        ALTER TABLE products ALTER COLUMN categories SET DEFAULT '{}';
      SQL
    end

    Product.find_in_batches(batch_size: 1000).with_index do |products, index|
      puts "Processing #{index + 1}"
      Product.where(id: products.map(&:id)).update_all(categories: [])
    end

    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      execute <<~SQL
        ALTER TABLE products ALTER COLUMN categories SET NOT NULL;
      SQL
    end
  end

  def down
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      remove_column :products, :categories
    end
  end
end
```

This is a slow migration and you have to wait for it to finish but it’ll prevent locking of the table.